# Real time sports scores from a web service?

Tags: web-services

Since [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643753/does-anybody-know-of-a-real-time-sports-scores-stats-web-service) is over 3 years old now, I was wondering if anyone was aware of any open web services out there where live sports scores can be downloaded from.

Any demos or sample code would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Might also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106/anyone-know-of-an-nfl-or-nba-api

Comment: Yes... And that post is almost 4 years old.  I'm in search of something more recent.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sportsdatallc.com/ is the best place I have found. They are expensive if you want realtime stats, but they have everything, and seem to be reliable.

If you want something free, then try ESPN APIs, but they do not yet offer score. They do offer team and player stats at the moment, however. I imagine they will eventually open up scores to the public.

Comment: It sucks that scores are only available for "strategic partners"